# Is it possible to match vim and gvim colorschemes?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, colorscheme

[This](https://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-color-scheme-syntax/) was a nice little article that somewhat demystified vim colors to me.

I downloaded and installed the [Base2Tone](https://base2t.one/) vim colorschemes, and set the following in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
colorscheme Base2Tone_PoolDark
hi LineNr ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=NONE
```

I was mostly satisfied with the result in `vim`:
[image]

But I ***much*** prefer how it renders in `gvim`:
[image]

**Is there some way I can get `vim`'s colorscheme rendering more like `gvim`'s?**

---

Note: I mentioned the `hi LineNr` because I'm curious why the line numbers *don't* render yellow in `gvim` - but I don't necessarily want to clutter this post with too many incidental questions - I'm mostly interested in the background color rendering. To my eye, it looks like the text (foreground?) colors are a pretty reasonable match.

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on @filbranden's answer, I tried `export TERM=xterm-true-color` and restarting `vim`, and this looks like it's on the right track, but it's still a bit off -- it looks like it's filling spaces past EOL with black; does anyone recognize the issue, and what setting to change so there isn't that mismatched background color?
[image]

Comment: *it looks like it's filling spaces past EOL with black* Does it help if you write this in your vimrc `set t_ut=`?

Comment: @user938271 - Yes, everything past EOL and also TABs (not evident from the screenshot). So only the background of alpha-num-space is rendered with the purple. Tried adding `set t_ut= `, but didn't seem to have any effect; but thank you.

Comment: Funny, I want to perform the exact opposite.  Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Highlight in gui or true color terminal with `:h termguicolors`  is not affect by `:h cterm`, `cterm` is used for 8, 16, 256 color terminal. This command should change gui LineNr:

```
hi LineNr guifg=#ff0000 guibg=#000000
```

A quick look at the [source](https://github.com/atelierbram/Base2Tone-vim/blob/master/colors/Base2Tone_PoolDark.vim), this colorscheme use only 16colors, it doesn't use ansi 16 colors, it works for gui, true color and 256color terminal.

If your terminal has truecolor, you can turn on  `termguicolors`, it will use `gui` color to render terminal.

If your terminal is 256color, you must setup your 256 color palette, otherwise it will be degraded.

### Change xterm-256color color palette

color palette is usually set by `Operating System Command (OSC)` characters, it's `ESC]` in `xterm`

```
ctlseqs.txt.gz
---------------------
Operating System Commands
...
OSC Ps ; Pt ST
...
            Ps = 4 ; c; spec -> Change Color Number c to the color spec-
          ified by spec.  This can be a name or RGB specification as per
          XParseColor.  Any number of c/spec pairs may be given.  The
          color numbers correspond to the ANSI colors 0-7, their bright
          versions 8-15, and if supported, the remainder of the 88-color
          or 256-color table.
```

It's a bit hard to read, it basically says you can change your 256 color palette by:

```
{OSC characters}4;{color index};{XParseColor color specification}{ST characters}
```

We already know OSC, color index is 0-255, ST is `ESC\`, You can find XParseColor specification in `man xparsecolor`:

```
...

COLOR NAMES
       An RGB Device specification is identified by the prefix ``rgb:'' and conforms to the follow‐
       ing syntax:

       rgb:<red>/<green>/<blue>
```

Put everything together:

```
printf "\033]4;235;rgb:30/30/30\033\\"
```

Above command will change color 235 to `#303030`

Different `TERM` use different escape sequece to change 256 color palette. This might only applied to xterm family terminal.

Popular colorscheme such as `gruvbox` will provide a shell script to help you setup your color palette.

Comment: Not sure I'm applying your suggestion correctly: I understand the general concept: i.e. a 256-color terminal can display 256 colors _at a time_ out of a total palette of however many colors. And that `printf` command is supposed to change color #235, which I think you determined is the background color used by the `Base2Tone_PoolDark` colorscheme. So I ran that command in my xterm-256color term, and restarted `vim`, and I see the background rendered in gray (just like the very first screenshot) instead of purple -- am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I tried a different color: like I used google's online color picker, and tried to pick color `#a175a0` by doing `printf "\033]4;235;rgb:a1/75/a0\033\\"` then restarting `vim`, but that also resulted in a gray background that looked the same as that very first screenshot.

Comment: @StoneThrow 235 is just a random color, I don't know if it's used in `Base2Tone-PoolDark`. You can check your colorscheme's [source](https://github.com/atelierbram/Base2Tone-vim/blob/master/colors/Base2Tone_PoolDark.vim), you need to change all colors used by your colorcheme.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way I can get vim's colorscheme rendering more like gvim's?

Yes! As long as your terminal supports "true color," you can ask Vim to use the gvim color settings of the colorscheme by enabling the [`'termguicolors'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27termguicolors%27) setting:

> When on, uses `highlight-guifg` and `highlight-guibg` attributes in the terminal (thus using 24-bit color).
>
> Requires a ISO-8613-3 compatible terminal. If setting this option does not work (produces a colorless UI) reading `xterm-true-color` might help.

Simply add this line to your vimrc:

```
set termguicolors
```

If that doesn't work, take a further look at the documentation to ensure your terminal supports this feature and is properly configured to use it.

---

Your terminal emulator, MobaXterm, is supposed to support "true color", so it should be possible to make it work.

If setting `TERM=xterm-true-color` is giving you trouble, then try to keep `TERM=xterm-256color` and set vim options `t_8f` and `t_8b` explicitly, as recommended in [`:help xterm-true-color`](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#xterm-true-color):

```
let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38:2:%lu:%lu:%lum"
let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48:2:%lu:%lu:%lum"
```

(And, if that doesn't work, try using semicolons instead of colons in those expressions.)

Comment: Doing this gave me a B&W colorscheme. This is a little bit outside my expertise, but I tried to read up on your answer, so now I think this is because my Terminal (MobaXTerm, ssh session to a Linux box) is setting `xterm-256color` -- do you think that's why? Also, I didn't quite understand the quote "reading xterm-true-color might help" -- does that mean I should set `$TERM` to `xterm-true-color` instead of `xterm-256color`?

Comment: Ah! Getting close! I manually did `export TERM=xterm-true-color`, then re-ran `vim`, and now the background color _where text is present_ looks the right color -- but it looks like TAB whitespace and anything past `EOL` is still black.

Comment: @StoneThrow Updated my answer with another suggestion you can try.

Comment: Some interesting results here: if I set `xterm-256color` and add those two lines (with semicolons instead of colons) and comment-out `set termguicolors`, the background is rendered a light gray (instead of purple). If I uncomment `set termguicolors`, then I get the mixed purple/black background rendering.  

If I set `xterm-true-color`, with `termguicolors` and those two lines, I get the mixed purple/black background, and without `termguicolors`, I get total B&W rendering.